# Relation between Feynman path integral and time ordering operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, path-integral

Is there any relationship between Feynman path integral approach and time ordering operator because both of the approaches obliterate the idea of noncommutativity of operators since in FPI the integrand is simply a function of c-value and in T ordering the operators are placed in the order of their t-value so $T(\hat{x}\hat{p})$ can be $\hat{x}\hat{p}$ or $\hat{p}\hat{x}$ depending on their t-value?

Comment: Feynman path integral approach actually (naturally) gives averages of time ordered operators. Look at Feynman's original paper for clear demonstration of this and the way commutation relationships are implemented in path integral formalism.

Comment: T-ordering operator actually preserves non-commutativity. It is a shorthand for the products of non-commuting operators that are already ordered according to time (due to the causality principle.) Feynman path integral does the same thing, but in a less transparent (to me) way.